# Cannot find symbol is displayed for noOfGames , score and name

Tags: java

import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld

{

```
 public static void main(String []args)
 {

 int score =0;
 int noOfGames =0;
 int noOfCorrectedGames =0; 
 String name;
 int age;


     int ran=0; 
     int guessno=0;
     int round_count=0;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in);  
    System.out.println("Enter your Name:");
    name = keyboard.next();

    System.out.println("Enter your age in Numeric:");
    age = keyboard.nextInt();


    //System.out.println("Random value is " + ran);

    if(age<7 && age>=4)
    {
        ran=randomNumberInRange(1, 20);     
    }
    else if(age<12 && age>=7)
    {
        ran=randomNumberInRange(1, 25);             
    }
    else if(age>=12)
    {
        ran=randomNumberInRange(1, 30);             
    }
    else if(age<4)
    {
        System.out.println("You are Strictly prohibited to use this " +
                "application including the laptop");            
        System.exit(0);         
    }




    for(int y=1;y<10;y++) //Play Till you Die
    {
        noOfGames = y;

        if(age<7 && age>=4)
        {
            ran=randomNumberInRange(1, 20);     
        }
        else if(age<12 && age>=7)
        {
            ran=randomNumberInRange(1, 25);             
        }
        else if(age>=12)
        {
            ran=randomNumberInRange(1, 30);             
        }
        else if(age<4)
        {
            System.out.println("You are Strictly prohibited to use this " +
                    "application including the laptop");            
            System.exit(0);         
        }


            for (int i=1;i<11;i++) // every student get a 10 attempts
            {
                round_count=i;

                System.out.println("Guess the Magical No(Numeric):");
                guessno = keyboard.nextInt();


                if(guessno==ran) //If Correct Answer
                {               
                    if(i>=1 && i<=3)
                    {
                        score=5;                
                    }
                    else if(i>=4 && i<=6)
                    {               
                        score=3;
                    }
                    else if(i>=7 && i<=10)
                    {               
                        score=1;
                    }  
                    noOfCorrectedGames++;

                    System.out.println("-------------------GAME OVER --------------------");
                    System.out.println("Do you want to Play again? Enter P; Do you want to Exit? Enter E; :");
                    String result = keyboard.next();        

                    if(result.equals("E"))
                    {
                        print_deadgame_results();
                        System.exit(0);             
                    }
                    else 
                    { 
                        break;
                    }     

                }
                else //If Wrong Answer
                {
                    if(ran >guessno)
                    {
                        System.out.println("GO HIGHER !");
                    }
                    else if(ran <guessno)
                    {
                        System.out.println("GO LOWER !");
                    }                       
                }   

            }

            if(round_count==10)
            {       
                System.out.println("-------------------GAME OVER --------------------");
                System.out.println("Do you want to Play again? Enter P; Do you want to Exit? Enter E; :");
                String result = keyboard.next();        

                if(result=="E")
                {
                    print_deadgame_results();
                    System.exit(0);             
                }
                else 
                {           
                }           
            }

    }

    print_deadgame_results();

}

public static int randomNumberInRange(int min, int max)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}

public static void print_deadgame_results()
{       
    System.out.println("=================== Final Score =======================");
    System.out.println("Total number of games played : " + noOfGames);
    System.out.println("Total number of games where correct guesses were made : " +noOfCorrectedGames);     
    System.out.println("Hello "+ name +", you scored "+ score +" out of possible "+ noOfGames +".");
}
```

}

HelloWorld.java:160: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("Total number of games played : " + noOfGames);
                                                               ^
  symbol:   variable noOfGames
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:161: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("Total number of games where correct guesses were made : " +noOfCorrectedGames);
                                                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable noOfCorrectedGames
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:162: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("Hello "+ name +", you scored "+ score +" out of possible "+ noOfGames +".");
                                     ^
  symbol:   variable name
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:162: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("Hello "+ name +", you scored "+ score +" out of possible "+ noOfGames +".");
                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable score
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:162: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("Hello "+ name +", you scored "+ score +" out of possible "+ noOfGames +".");
                                                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable noOfGames
  location: class HelloWorld

Comment: `noOfGames` is only in scope in the `main()`

Comment: what can i do for this. please please explain me

Comment: You can pass it to the method as an argument. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: You should start by reading a good book or tutorial. And hint: also read about Java naming conventions.

Comment: @HirushaMadushani Compare the *parameters* (the things in `()`) of your `randomNumberInRange(int min, int max)` with your `print_deadgame_results()`.

Comment: can you give me an example? @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`noOfGames` is a local variable in your `main` method. If you want to use it in the `print_deadgame_results` method, you should either pass it to it as an argument, or convert it to a static member.

Comment: how can i add as an arguement?